# c# Get Path from a busy file using openFileDialog in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I'm trying go get a path to a 'busy' file using openfiledialog in winforms and C#. Using the following code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            this.dbPath = this.textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

When I point to the file in question  I get the following error:

**Error Message:**

> MyDbContext.mdf
>
> This file is in use.
>
> Enter a new name or close the file that's open in another program.

Which is fine, because I already know the file is in use, all I want is to store the file path into a string, **without** opening it.

Perhaps openfiledalog is the wrong option here, after all I don't want to open the file, only to list it's path. However I didn't find anything else in winforms that points to a file.

Is there any other means to achieve what I want?

Comment: Please add the error message to your question as *text*. Images are not searchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting ValidateNames to false before ShowDialog()

```
openFileDialog1.ValidateNames = false;
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Comment: While this is the correct and accepted answer, it may help other users if you [edit]ed your answer to include **why**, perhaps including a link to the MSDN documentation.